# How can I change the n-th value of a named range in Excel VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Here's a table about fruits:

[image]

These fruits are the names of named ranges in Column A, too. For example, if I type the following:

```
=INDEX(apple, 1, 1)
```

then the result is 1.

My question is: How can I change the n-th value of a named range in Excel VBA? I'd like to add a new value to the first element of named range 'apple', like:

```
"Range("apple",1,1).Value = 2"
```

How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Range("apple",1,1).Value = 2`

you can refer to named ranges in VBA with `Range` property, and therefore you access them as a range object, to refer to its cells, use the `Cells` property:

```
Range("apple").Cells(1,1).Value = 2
```